# php stripping a particular result from an output

Tags: php, preg-replace, shell-exec

I am using php to grab a shell output that lists all the `meetme` channels for me. I just want to grab the `Conf Num` that has `0001` from the bottom up. In my example below, I would like to assign variable: `$confnum="32";`

Here is my code so far:

```
$output = shell_exec("asterisk -rx 'meetme list'");

echo $output;
```

Please help me take the results from $output.

Here's what you'll get when executing the meet.php file

```
[root@C1033-TF agi-bin]# php meet.php
Conf Num       Parties        Marked     Activity  Creation  Locked
67             0001       N/A        00:00:16  Dynamic   No    
28             0001       N/A        00:00:19  Dynamic   No    
65             0001       N/A        00:01:14  Dynamic   No    
42             0001       N/A        00:01:18  Dynamic   No    
32             0001       N/A        00:04:18  Dynamic   No    
* Total number of MeetMe users: 5
```

Please keep in mind that sometime there will be more than just 0001 Parties in the Conf Num. In the example above, I just want to grab the line:

```
32             0001       N/A        00:04:18  Dynamic   No
```

This is the last line that has 0001 therefore assign $confnum="32"; to it.

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exec instead of shell_exec and iterate through the output lines:

```
<?php
$output = array();
exec("asterisk -rx 'meetme list'", $output);

foreach ($output as $line) {
   if (preg_match('/^32\s/', $line)) { //Check line starts with 32
      echo $line;
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
<?php
$output = array();
exec("asterisk -rx 'meetme list'", $output);

$lines = sizeof($output);    
for ($i = $lines -1; $i >=0 ; $i--) {
   if (preg_match('/^(\d+)\s+0001\s/', $output[$i], $matches)) { //Check line contains 0001
      $firstNumber = $matches[1];
      echo $firstNumber;
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: but sometimes it's not 32... i just want the last line conf numb that has 0001 with it

Comment: I tried this and got this error: PHP Warning:  shell_exec() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/meet2.php on line 3

Comment: Sorry, I meant exec instead of shell_exec. I allready edited the answer

Comment: How can I just grab the first set of numbers not the entire line?

Comment: You mean the 32 in that case? I modified the script, you should get it in the $firstNumber var.

Comment: I found it quite devastating just taking the last line, is there any way we can random our selection that has 0001 ? meaning, random the picking, don't pick just the last line.

Comment: I don't know if I really understood what you need, but you could shuffle the array before iterating throught it. shuffle($output)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, assuming Linux, you can do this purely in shell:

- filter last line: `grep -v 'Total number of MeetMe isers'`
- filter first line: `grep -v 'Conf Num'`
- and print only one `Conf Num`: `awk 'BEGIN{ result=""; } {if( $2 == "0001"){result=$1;}} END {print result;}'`

So the whole code:

```
$output = shell_exec("asterisk -rx 'meetme list' | grep -v 'Total number of MeetMe isers' | grep -v 'Conf Num' | awk 'BEGIN{ result=\"\"; } {if( \$2 == \"0001\"){result=$1;}} END {print result;}'");
// $output should contain your data :)
```

Or use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$output = shell_exec("asterisk -rx 'meetme list'");
$matches = array();
$result = null;
preg_match_all('~^\s*(\\d+)\\s+0001~', $output, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach( $matches as $match ){
  $result = $match[1];
}
```

In reaction to comment:

You should study regular expression syntax and meaning of [`\d`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) and [`+`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php). `\d+` will match `0`, `01` or `00000000000000000000000000000000` :).

Comment: I just tried the 1st shell method, and I this error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/meet.php on line 3

Comment: your second recommend works great, but it gives me the entire line, I just want the Conf Num digits....

Comment: Also that conf number is not always just double digits, it could be 3-4 digits as well

Comment: @thevoipman I fixed not escaped `"` in string. you **SHOULD** do that on your own, not just "gimme teh kodes" and paste it without thinking. For the second part... Try using `print_r( $matches)` and `print_r( $match)` inside the loop. Again, uses brain please, don't just copy codes.

Comment: I'm trying to do my best to debug, however, I am getting empty results

Comment: @thevoipman what's in $matches after `preg_match_all` call, can you post it on pastebin?

Comment: I think i found the answer i'm looking for. I dont know what pastebin is :(

Comment: Thank you, I really like your shell single line, it looks really nice.